# How to figure out the SQL code for a different owners view

Tags: sql, oracle, view, oracle-sqldeveloper

In my database I have access to another owner's tables and views. However, I would like to know the SQL code used to create a specific view by the owner `Bob` called `test_v`. In SQL developer, I have tried to click on that view and click on SQL on the top, to try and view some sort of the SQL. Is there any way I can see the code used to create the view? Possibly an SQL statement I can use?

Not sure else to make this question more clear. Please let me know how else I can do this.

Comment: What happened when you clicked on the view (I assume you mean under 'other users' objects in the browser) and then the SQL tab? Are you able to see the view if you query `all_views`?

Comment: You are correct. I click on `other users` > `Bob` (bob is the owner) > `views` > `test_v` (what the view is called). I am able to do `select view_name from all_views`

Comment: @ZoeyMalkov - What happened when you clicked on the view name?  What happens when you right click on the view and export the DDL?

Comment: @JustinCave When I click on the view name on SQL Developer, it shows me all the `column_name`, `data_type` etc. Essentially shows me the `Columns` tab. I can also click on the `data` tab and see the data as well. I have other options too, like `SQL` but its empty. How can I export the DDL? Without taking all the data with me (there is too much data)

Comment: @ZoeyMalkov - In the export dialog, you can choose whether to include data or not.  It sounds like you probably have access to the objects themselves but not the code of those objects.

Comment: @JustinCave Do I go to `tools` > `database export`?

Comment: @ZoeyMalkov - Right click on the view.  Pick "Export".  Or pick "Quick DDL" if you don't want to have any options for what DDL to include.